# PHP setcookie doesn't work on IE8

Tags: php

the following code doesn't work on IE8.
i tried print_r ($_COOKIE) but it returned array(); 
please help me.

```
  1 <?php
  2 $currentTime = time();
  3 
  4 $cookieName   = "go.hyde";
  5 $cookiePath   = "/";
  6 $cookieDomain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  7 $cookieValue  = strval($currentTime);       // value is issue time (Unix Time)
  8 $cookieExpire = strval($currentTime + 600); // expire is 10 minutes after issuing cookie
  9 
 10 setcookie($cookieName,
 11     $cookieValue,
 12     $cookieExpire,
 13     $cookiePath,
 14     $cookieDomain);
 15
```

Comment: Did you check if coockie are active on IE?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: no error found if you have a solution could you give me.

Comment: How can i have a solution If i dont know the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try without cookie path and cookie domain

```
setcookie($cookieName,$cookieValue,$cookieExpire);
```

check if cookies are enabled in IE

**============== EDIT ================**

I think I got it, try this:

```
<?
$currentTime = time();
$cookieName   = "gohyde";
$cookieValue  = strval($currentTime);       // value is issue time (Unix Time)
$cookieExpire = strval($currentTime + 600); // expire is 10 minutes after issuing cookie 
setcookie($cookieName,
$cookieValue,
$cookieExpire);
echo $_COOKIE[$cookieName];
?>
```

without cookie path and cookie domain. and no "." dot in the cookie name.

Comment: thx for your quick responce. I've tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: I have edited the post, try again. I think I this it is fixed